# a question on cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Suppose $S$ and $T$ are sets such that $|S|=|T|$
Prove that $|\mathcal{P}(S)|=|\mathcal{P}(T)|$.

To start with, $|S|<|\mathcal{P}(S)|$; $|T|<|\mathcal{P}(T)|$.

Just the statement itself sounds so obvious, that it confuses me a lot. I guess it might have something to do with Cantor-Bernstein Theorem but I do not know how

Comment: Since $|S| = |T|$, there is some bijective function between $f \colon S \to T$. Can we use (expand) this function somehow to create a bijection $f_P \colon P(S) \to P(T)$?

Comment: The stuff you wrote about $|S|\lt |P(S)|$ is true, but not needed.

Answer (score 3):

No. You don't need the Cantor-Bernstein theorem.

Since $|S|=|T|$, you have a bijection $f$ between $S$ and $T$. Define $\varphi:P(S)\to P(T)$ like as 
\[\varphi(X) = \{ f(x) : x\in X\}.\]
You can check that $\varphi$ is 1-1 and onto.